# Updating a PHP variable using AJAX

Tags: php, ajax

I have a results page that displays graphs for answers from a survey. The graphs are generated through a PHP file that executes SQL. The results page needs to incorporate some filtering, so I am trying to use AJAX to update the SQL to display without reloading said results page.

The type of filter is selected via a form;

```
<form name="sqlselector" action= "javascript" onsubmit"ajaxFunction('barscompleteCCC.php?     course=' + document.getElementById('course').value);">

<select name="course"> 
<option value="All">All</option>
<?php $result= mysql_query('SELECT * FROM tCourse'); ?> 
<?php while($row= mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) 
{ ?> 
    <option value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($row['CourseID']);?>"> 
        <?php echo htmlspecialchars($row['CourseName']); ?> 
    </option> 
<?php 
} 
?> 
</select>
<input type="submit" value="Build">
</form>
```

the Ajax is:

```
ajaxConnection.onreadystatechange = ajaxReply; // whenever the ready state is changed
ajaxConnection.open('GET', url, true); // opens a request to server
ajaxConnection.send(null); // closes the request
// Now, the code waits unless the ready state changes.
// After every change ajaxReply() is executed

    return true;

} // end function ajaxFunction

function ajaxReply() { // your code's logic goes here
    if (ajaxConnection.readyState == 4) 
    { // 4 mean page loaded successfully
        if (ajaxConnection.status == 200) 
        { // 200 mean all is OK
            document.getElementById('course').innerHTML =   ajaxConnection.responseText;            
        } // end if
        else 
        { // if the status code is anything else (a rare case though)
            alert('Something weird occurred. HTTP error code ' + ajaxConnection.status.toString() + 'yoko.');
            return; // exit
        }
    } // end if
```

The variable in question that I would like to dynamically change, is in the PHP file:

```
session_start();
$course = $_GET['course'];
```

Please, any help would be greatly appreciated. :-)

Comment: What is the value of "url"? That would need to be something like: 'yoururl.php?course='+selectedvalue

Comment: its got a value      course=' + document.getElementById('course').value);

Comment: im guessing its something within my ajax script

Comment: why make it so complicated? my $0.02 - use the ajax to reload the graph `<img src=NEW_URL>`

Comment: the 'url' variable has to be 'url_where_the_php_is?course='+ document.getElementById('course').value;  aside from that I don't see anything wrong, what kind of error, or wrong behaviour are you having?

Comment: i think its in the ajax script, the variable doesnt seem to change... im have a single 'graph building php file that i submit variables to ... so to display them i use

Comment: <?php
for ($i = 1; $i < 39; $i++)
{
 $sqlquestion = 'SELECT Question FROM tquestion WHERE QuestionID = '.$i.'';
 $questiontext = mysql_query($sqlquestion,$odbc) or die ("can not run query");
 $q = mysql_fetch_row($questiontext);
 
 ?>
    <div id="question"><?php echo $i. ') ' .$q[0];?></div>
    <?php
 if ($i == 5)
 {
  ?>
  <div id="answer5"><iframe src="Answer5.php" width="945px"></iframe></div>
        <div id="spacer"></div>
        <?php
 } 

 if ($i == 20)
 {
  ?>
  <div id="answer5"><iframe src="Answer20.php" width="945px"></iframe></div>
        <div id="spacer"></div>
        <?php

Comment: sorry thought it would come out better than that heres the short an narrow version;

Comment: if ($i != 5 && $i != 20 && $i != 21 && $i != 27 && $i != 32)
 {
 ?>
    <div id="bars"><img src="barscompleteCCC.php?graph=<?php echo $i;?>"></div>
    <div id="lines"><img src="square222.php?graph=<?php echo $i;?>"></div>
    <div id="spacer"></div>
    <?php
 }